# SQL Grammer Exception. Problem in mapping and saving the columns in hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a weird question

```
    CREATE TABLE comment(
    commentId int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    commentName varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,

    primary key(commentId)

    );

    CREATE TABLE post(
    postId int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    postName varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    primary key(postId),
    `comment_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    KEY `FK_COMMENT_ID_idx` (`comment_id`),

    CONSTRAINT `FK_COMMENT` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`comment_id`) 
    REFERENCES `comment` (`commentId`) 

    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    );
```

I want to have unidirectional relationship between post and comment. One Post has many comments.
Where should I be defining the foreign key constraint. In comment table or in post table (like in the code).
I am using hibernate to save the post and comment. But I m not getting desired result.

My Hibernate code:

Comment.java

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table(name="comment")
public class Comment {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="commentId")
private int commentId;

@Column(name="commentName")
private String commentName;

public Comment() {
    
}

public Comment(String commentName) {
    this.commentName = commentName;
}

public int getCommentId() {
    return commentId;
}

public void setCommentId(int commentId) {
    this.commentId = commentId;
}

public String getCommentName() {
    return commentName;
}

public void setCommentName(String commentName) {
    this.commentName = commentName;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Comment [commentId=" + commentId + ", commentName=" + commentName + "]";
}
     }
```

Post.java

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity
    @Table(name="post")
    public class Post {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="postId")
private int postId;

@Column(name="postName")
private String postName;


@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="comment_id")
private List<Comment> comments;

public Post() {
    
}

public Post(String postName) {
    
    this.postName = postName;
}

public int getPostId() {
    return postId;
}

public void setPostId(int postId) {
    this.postId = postId;
}

public String getPostName() {
    return postName;
}

public void setPostName(String postName) {
    this.postName = postName;
}



public List<Comment> getComments() {
    return comments;
}

public void setComments(List<Comment> comments) {
    this.comments = comments;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "POST [postId=" + postId + ", postName=" + postName + "]";
}

public void add(Comment theComment)
{
    if(comments==null)
    {
        comments=new ArrayList<>();
    }
    comments.add(theComment);
    }
}
```

CreatePostComment.java

```
    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

    import com.learnJava.entity.Comment;
    import com.learnJava.entity.Post;

    public class CreatePostComment {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SessionFactory factory=
            new Configuration()
            .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
            .addAnnotatedClass(Post.class)
            .addAnnotatedClass(Comment.class)
            .buildSessionFactory();
    
    Session session= factory.getCurrentSession();
    
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        
        
        Comment theComment=new Comment("Nice Comment");
        
        Post thePost= new Post("Amazing Post");
        
        thePost.add(theComment);
        
        session.save(thePost);
        
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        session.close();
        factory.close();
    }

}

    }
```

Output

```
Nov 12, 2020 10:38:54 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.19.Final
Nov 12, 2020 10:38:55 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
Nov 12, 2020 10:38:56 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Nov 12, 2020 10:38:56 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hb-04-one-to-many-uni?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC]
Nov 12, 2020 10:38:56 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=hbstudent, password=****}
Nov 12, 2020 10:38:56 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Nov 12, 2020 10:38:56 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Nov 12, 2020 10:38:57 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Hibernate: insert into post (postName) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into comment (commentName) values (?)
Hibernate: update comment set comment_id=? where commentId=?
Nov 12, 2020 10:38:59 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
Nov 12, 2020 10:38:59 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Unknown column 'comment_id' in 'field list'
Nov 12, 2020 10:38:59 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1364)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:451)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3210)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2378)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:447)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
    at com.learnJava.hibernate.CreatePostComment.main(CreatePostComment.java:35)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1357)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.OneToManyPersister.recreate(OneToManyPersister.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1360)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'comment_id' in 'field list'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1347)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
    ... 21 more
Nov 12, 2020 10:38:59 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PoolState stop
INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hb-04-one-to-many-uni?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC]
```

Comment: Why do you mix quoted and unquoted identifiers? It can make your code more error-prone. Also why do you have different types for id field in comment and post? And finally, how can you imagine insert multiple comments that relate to single post and save reference to multiple `ID`s in single integer value?

Answer (score 1):

> One Post has many comments

If that is how it's **supposed** to be, then your entire structure is backwards. Instead of the post referencing the comments, the comments must reference the posts.

```
CREATE TABLE post(
    id int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    name varchar(45),
    content text,
    primary key(id)
);

CREATE TABLE comment(
    id int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    post_id int(10) not null,
    name varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    content text not null,
    primary key(id),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_post` FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) 
    REFERENCES `post` (`id`) 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

Then in your Java classes Comment should have:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
private Post post;
```

Here the `JoinColumn` specifies the **column** name in the database, within the `comment` table.

And the Post class should have:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = false)
private List<Comment> comments;
```

Here the `mappedBy` specifies the **field** name within the child java class that refers to this parent.

Now normally you might want the `cascade` value to be `CascadeType.ALL`, but the way you've specified the foreign key actions suggests you don't want removals, so we don't keep those, and also don't remove orphans (Comments that have been removed from the list).

Before persisting them, you have to run

```
theComment.setPost(thePost);
```

on each comment, or you will get constraint violations.